# Styling of devexpress elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, devexpress

I've got a question in regards to styling the appearance of devexpress elements (and comboboxes in particular). I've looked through demos and also looked for tutorials but didn't find anything that seemed to work so far (I know it must work somehow though).

Below is an example of how I create a combobox. The problem I have is that it looks like shown on the image at the end of this post. With settings.Properties.Native=true it looks like a normal combobox, but if set to false it looks completely different (and sadly is way too big). 
So my question is: How can I format it to look at least somewhat similar to a normal combobox (sizewise)? (with other words, what is a common way to do that in such cases?
and if done via CSS, what keywords would I have to use there,...?)

Tnx

```
Kategorie  @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(
                    settings => {
                        settings.Name = "ProductCategory";
                        settings.Width = 300;
                        settings.SelectedIndex = 0;
                        settings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.DropDownStyle.DropDown;
                        settings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
                        settings.Properties.TextField = "Name";

                        settings.Properties.DisplayFormatInEditMode = false;
                        settings.Properties.Native = false;
                        settings.Properties.TextFormatString = "{0}";
                        settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "{0}";
                        settings.Properties.ValueField = "Id";
                        settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
                    }
  ).BindList(Categories).GetHtml()
```

---

[image: Image of how a combobox looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose **ASPxThemeBuilder** tool from the Start -> All Programs -> Developer Express xxx -> Components -> Tools -> ASPxThemeBuilder.

Related documentation:

- [ASPxThemeBuilder](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#ASPxThemeBuilder/CustomDocument10781)
- [ASPxThemeDeployer](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#ASPxThemeDeployer/CustomDocument5500)

Comment: Tnx, I tried that tool out. Looks nice. If I may ask there: How do I then include this theme into the program / combobox? 
(I don't have much experience with devexpress so far so I know mostly basic things like how to create fields and boxes,...)

Comment: then you should use devexpress theme deployer tool. that will generate css and images and then you should include this css in your project.

Comment: Thanks. I currently still have the problem that I have problems with using the themes but I fear that is a problem with how the project was created. Thus it is unrelated to the original question and I count the original question as solved.

Tnx again